# Python Logical Operation

Tags: python, operators, logic, scrapy

I'm pretty new to python and I'm working on a web scraping project using the Scrapy library. I'm not using the built in domain restriction because I want to check if any of the links to pages outside the domain are dead. However, I still want to treat pages within the domain differently from those outside it and am trying to manually determine if a site is within the domain before parsing the response.

Response URL:

```
http://www.siteSection1.domainName.com
```

If Statement:

```
if 'domainName.com' and ('siteSection1' or 'siteSection2' or 'siteSection3') in response.url:
    parsePageInDomain()
```

The above statement is true (the page is parsed) if 'siteSection1' is the first to appear in the list of or's but it will not parse the page if the response url is the same but the if statement were the following:

```
if 'domainName.com' and ('siteSection2' or 'siteSection1' or 'siteSection3') in response.url:
        parsePageInDomain()
```

What am I doing wrong here? I haven't been able to think through what is going on with the logical operators very clearly and any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`or` doesn't work that way. Try `any`:

```
if 'domainName.com' in response.url and any(name in response.url for name in ('siteSection1', 'siteSection2', 'siteSection3')):
```

What's going on here is that `or` returns a logical `or` of its two arguments - `x or y` returns `x` if `x` evaluates to `True`, which for a string means it's not empty, or `y` if `x` does not evaluate to `True`. So `('siteSection1' or 'siteSection2' or 'siteSection3')` evaluates to `'siteSection1'` because `'siteSection1'` is `True` when considered as a boolean.

Moreover, you're also using `and` to combine your criteria. `and` returns its first argument if that argument evaluates to `False`, or its second if the first argument evaluates to `True`. Therefore, `if x and y in z` does not test to see whether both `x` and `y` are in `z`. `in` has higher precedence than `and` - and I had to [look that up](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) - so that
tests `if x and (y in z)`. Again, `domainName.com` evaluates as True, so this will return just `y in z`.

`any`, conversely, is a built in function that takes an iterable of booleans and returns `True` or `False` - `True` if any of them are `True`, `False` otherwise. It stops its work as soon as it hits a `True` value, so it's efficient. I'm using a generator expression to tell it to keep checking your three different possible strings to see if any of them are in your response url.

Comment: Thanks Peter, this was very informative. Great answer, and much appreciated!